# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus with e

Tags: calculus, integration

How do you use the fundamental theorem of calculus to find:
\begin{align}
{d\over dx }\int_1^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{e^{t^2}}{4t}\,dt
\end{align}

I know that you can't use the fundamental theorem of calculus directly because the upper bound is $\sqrt{x}$ not $x$. However, I don't know how to integrate this expression. When I try using an online calculator it introduces a new variable Ei. I was wondering if there is an easier way to solve this without integrating or without Ei.

Thank you.

Comment: Perform the change of integration variables from $t$ to $s$ via $s=t^2$. $\operatorname{Ei}$ is not a new variable, it is the exponential integral function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the chain rule, we have
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\sqrt{x}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\sqrt{x}}.$$
Using this, we can then apply the Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\sqrt{x}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\sqrt{x}}\int_1^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{e^{t^2}}{4t}\,\mathrm{d}t
=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\frac{e^x}{4\sqrt{x}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to see why this question is about the Chain Rule: because there's some expression (i.e., a function) of $x$ in a place where we expect to see $x$, so that's an inside function inside another function (no pun intended) — that is, we're looking at a composition of functions, and thus finding the derivative of that requires the Chain Rule.

Less informally. Let's define $\displaystyle f(x)=\int_1^x\frac{e^{t^2}}{4t}\mathrm{d}t$. Then you're asked to find the derivative of $f(\sqrt{x})$. To make this composition of functions even more explicit, let's call $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$. Then, by the Chain Rule, $[f(g(x))]'=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$. Note that
$$f'(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[\int_1^x\frac{e^{t^2}}{4t}\mathrm{d}t\right]=\frac{e^{x^2}}{4x}.$$
Then:
$$[f(g(x))]'=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)=\frac{e^{\sqrt{x}^2}}{4\sqrt{x}}\cdot(\sqrt{x})'=\ldots,$$
and I hope you can finish this from here.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use the most general form of the fundamental theorem of calculus ?

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t)\,dt=f(b(x))\, b'(x)-f(a(x)) \,a'(x)$$